# What is the error in the code and the SQL query? Why is nothing is displayed on the web page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, left-join, echo

I am creating a web page that display for the user at first 4 dropdown lists that includes a retrieved data from MYSQL database. where each dropdown list represent 1 column in different tables.

I am using wordpress and **$wpdb** class

What I need is to be able to display the result to the user based on the user selections.

**Example:**

```
site id - site name - owner name - owner contact -  lat - long -  company name....
```

and all related columns.

The problem is that the system is just displaying the data selected in the dropdown list ... it looks like the system just return the data from the dropdown list and not from the database.

How can I fix this?

I will display part of the code and an image of the web page.

[image: the first 4 columns are the selected input of the user the rest is the info that are related to the user's selections]

Code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: search info
    */

    get_header();
    ?>

    <?php
    // code for submit button ation
    global $wpdb;
//variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)


if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
{

   if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
      { 
       $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
      }
      else { $site_name=""; }

    if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
     {
      $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 
     } 
     else { $owner_name=""; }

     if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
     {
      $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];
     } 
     else { $company_name=""; }

    if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
    { 
     $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 
    }
    else { $Subcontractor_name="";}

//query to retrieve all related info of the selected data from the dropdown list  
$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("select 

site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
where 
site_info.siteNAME = `$site_name` 
AND
owner_info.ownerNAME = `$owner_name`
AND
company_info.companyNAME = `$company_name`
AND
subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME = `$Subcontractor_name`
 " , ARRAY_A);

$site_id = 'siteID';
$site_id = (array)$site_id;
$equipment_type = 'equipmentTYPE';
$equipment_type = (array)$equipment_type;
$lat='latitude';
$lat = (array)$lat;
$long='longitude';
$long = (array)$long;
$height = 'height';
$height = (array)$height;
$owner_contact = 'ownerCONTACT';
$owner_contact = (array)$owner_contact;
$sub_contact = 'subcontractorCONTACT';
$sub_contact = (array)$sub_contact;
$sub_company = 'subcontractorCOMPANY';
$sub_company = (array)$sub_company;

?>

    <table width="30%" >
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
           <td>Site ID</td>
           <td>Equipment Type</td>
           <td> Lattitude</td>
           <td>Longitude </td>
           <td> Height</td>
           <td> Owner Contact</td>
           <td> Sub Contact</td>
           <td> Sub company Name</td>



         </tr>
         <tr>
  <?php   
         foreach ($query_submit as $query)
     {
     echo "<table>";
     echo   "<tr>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[siteNAME]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>", $query[ownerNAME] ."</td>";
     echo       "<td>", $query[companyNAME] ."</td>";
     echo       "<td>", $query[subcontractorNAME]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[siteID ]."</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[equipmentTYPE]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[latitude]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[longitude]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[height]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[ownerCONTACT]. "</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[subcontractorCONTACT ]."</td>";
     echo       "<td>" ,$query[subcontractorCOMPANY]. "</td>";
     echo  "</tr>";
     echo"</table>";   
     }
   ?>  
         </tr>
    </table>
 <?php    
}  
?>
```

After clicking of the submit button nothing is display ... where is the error?

Comment: Incidentally, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: okk but i need to retrieve data from these tables  with taking into consideration  the user selections from the dropdown list

Comment: Hence why my comment is 'incidental'

Comment: @  Strawberry   do you know how  achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem the error was in the displaying  using echo ..i should use this format **echo"".$obj->siteNAME."";**.

thank you for your answers and comments